# how to quick edit simple product grid list in configurable product in magento2

Tags: datagridview

In Magento admin, I want inline edit qty, price and weight value of simple product in configurable product page in admin.  I am not able to find quick edit simple product grid list in configurable product detail in admin in magento2.